# OData $search support in Teiid vs Jboss Data Virtualization

Tags: jboss, odata, teiid

I'm looking to use Salesforce to, using Odata, connect to Teiid+Wildfly, which in turn connects to SQL Server.

When I read the documentation for Teiid 13, under limitations, it says OData $search is not supported.

http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/13.0.x/content/client-dev/OData4_Support.html

> The following feature limitations currently apply.
>
> - search is not supported
> - delta processing is not supported
> - data-aggregation extension to specification is not supported
> - $it usage is limited to only primitive collection properties

However when I read the documentation for Jboss Data Virtualization, under limitations, it doesn't list that $search is not supported.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_data_virtualization/6.4/html/development_guide_volume_1_client_development/ch08s02

> The following feature limitations apply:
>
> - Delta processing is not supported.
> - The data-aggregation extension to the specification is not supported."

Anyone know why there's a difference? Does the paid JBoss flavour have extra code allowing OData $search parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$search is not available in the JBoss Data Virtualization either, I would think it is a documentation issue.

The reason $search is not implemented as $search expected to works on all the content like cache search, which would be a very expensive operation in Teiid as it does not hold any content. I would think one needs an Elastic Search like backend integration to support for this where all the content is also cached.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated.